# How to use "is_unique" in Codeigniter and database is an mongodb

Tags: php, json, mongodb, codeigniter

how to make an username as unique in validation and output is in "JSON". Actually I'm using Codeigniter to build a application and MongoDB as database. I don't know whether "is_unique" working in mongodb or not but I tried but its not working.

Controller:

public function create_customer()
    {

```
 $this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

if($this->input->post('username') != $original_value) {
    $is_unique =  '|is_unique[customer.username]'
} else {
     $is_unique =  ''
}
// field name, error message, validation rules
$this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean'.$is_unique);
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_number', 'Phonenumber', 'trim|required|numeric|min_length[10]|max_length[10]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{   
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 'FALSE')); 
}   
else
{
    $this->load->model('general/customer');
    $new_customer[CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME]=$this->input->post('first_name');
    $new_customer[CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME]=$this->input->post('last_name');
    $new_customer[CUSTOMER_EMAIL]=$this->input->post('email_address');
    $new_customer[CUSTOMER_USERNAME]=$this->input->post('username');
    $new_customer[CUSTOMER_PHONE]=$this->input->post('phone_number');
    $new_customer[CUSTOMER_PASSWORD]=$this->input->post('password');
    $this->customer->is_unique();
    $query = $this->customer->add($new_customer);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 'TRUE'));
}   
}
```

Model:

```
public function is_unique()
{
    $query = $this->mongo_db->select('username');
    $result = mongo_db($query);
    $count = mongo_db_num_rows($result);
    if ($count>0) {
    echo 'Sorry! This Username already exists!';
    } 
    else
    {

     $insert = $this->mongo_db->insert(CUSTOMER, $new_customer);
     return $insert;
    }
```

}

This is my code. I wanted to keep username as unique in the application.
Please help me to complete the application.

Comment: What is not working? What are your results? You don't need to write the is_unique function, it's built into CodeIgniter's Form_validation library.

Comment: Actually one customer must have one username and it shouldn't be same for other customer. If any customer entered some username in my application it should through throw error or message like "UserName  Already exists". But now i did some modifications in my application and now it works fine. Here is my modified code.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

public function create_customer()

```
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_number', 'Phonenumber', 'trim|required|numeric|min_length[10]|max_length[10]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {   
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('success' => 'FALSE')); 
    }   
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('general/customer');
        $new_customer[CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME]=$this->input->post('first_name');
        $new_customer[CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME]=$this->input->post('last_name');
        $new_customer[CUSTOMER_EMAIL]=$this->input->post('email_address');
        $new_customer[CUSTOMER_USERNAME]=$this->input->post('username');
        $new_customer[CUSTOMER_PHONE]=$this->input->post('phone_number');
        $new_customer[CUSTOMER_PASSWORD]=$this->input->post('password');
        if($this->customer->is_unique($new_customer[CUSTOMER_USERNAME]))
        { 
           $query = $this->customer->add($new_customer);
           header('Content-Type: application/json');
           echo json_encode(array('success' => 'TRUE'));
        }
        else
        {
           header('Content-Type: application/json');
           echo json_encode(array('success' => 'FALSE'));
        }
     }  
}
```

Model:

```
function is_unique($username)

{
    $this->mongo_db->where(CUSTOMER_USERNAME, $username);
    $query = $this->mongo_db->get(CUSTOMER);
    return (count($query) == 0 ? true : false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The model code above by Ganesh UG doesn't exactly work for me.

Change the return statement to:

```
return (count((array)$query) == 0 ? true : false);
```